# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar For Each dentro de un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, foreach

Tengo la siguiente consulta, He creado un Array de objetos, pero no logro obtener los datos de los array que están dentro de las propiedades, en este caso acceder "armaslista"

```
let arrayObjetos = [
{
    nombre: 'Spider-Man',
    edad: 17,
    superpoderes: ['Escalar', 'Tela de Araña', 'Super agilidad'],
    armas: false,
    armasLista: []
},
{
    nombre: 'Hulk',
    edad: 32,
    superpoderes: ['Super Fuerza', 'Cabreo Maximo', 'Color verde'],
    armas: false,
    armasLista: []
},
{
    nombre: 'Iron Man',
    edad: 41,
    superpoderes: ['Tecnologia', 'Inteligencia', 'Cash'],
    armas: true,
    armasLista: ['Robots', 'Laser', 'Misiles']
},
```

];

Aqui utilice forEach para obtener el nombre y mostrar los que tienen arma, pero no logre obtener con el buble forEach los array de armasLista.

```
arrayObjetos.forEach(heroe => {
if(heroe.armas===true) {
    console.log('tiene armas')
}
```

})

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y como intentaste eso?

Comment: Hola que tal, prueba así `arrayObjetos.forEach( ({ armas, armasLista}) => { if (armas) {console.log(`${armasLista}`); } });`, espero te sirva;  en la parte del console.log de `$armasLista`, hay backticks de interpolación para que lo tomes en cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para iterar sobre un array dentro de un objeto, basta con utilizar otra instrucción ciclica. En este caso, `heroe.armaLista.forEach()` deberia de bastar.

Además, como un consejo, aquellos valores que sean boléanos (`true`/`false`), no es necesario compararlos con un `===` pues estos mismos indican si la condición o no se cumple. Esto aplica para cualquier lenguaje de programación.

```js
let arrayObjetos = [
{
    nombre: 'Spider-Man',
    edad: 17,
    superpoderes: ['Escalar', 'Tela de Araña', 'Super agilidad'],
    armas: false,
    armasLista: []
},
{
    nombre: 'Hulk',
    edad: 32,
    superpoderes: ['Super Fuerza', 'Cabreo Maximo', 'Color verde'],
    armas: false,
    armasLista: []
},
{
    nombre: 'Iron Man',
    edad: 41,
    superpoderes: ['Tecnologia', 'Inteligencia', 'Cash'],
    armas: true,
    armasLista: ['Robots', 'Laser', 'Misiles']
}];

arrayObjetos.forEach(heroe => {
    // Agregue esta linea para comprobar que heroe estaba iterando.
    //console.log(heroe.nombre);
    if(heroe.armas)
        console.log("Tiene armas");
        heroe.armasLista.forEach(arma => console.log(arma));
    // Tambien agrege el else para comprobar que funcionara perfectamente.
    //else
    //    console.log("No tiene armas");
});
```